# Spring Batch - How to create a custom writer that extends flatfileitemwriter to write in a csv file in Java

Tags: java, spring-batch

How do I create a custom writer that extends flatfileitemwriter to write in a csv file ? I'm very new to Spring Batch and I looked everywhere for an example but couldn't find one that creates a class that extends flatfileitemwriter and implements it to write a csv file. Could someone please write a working example for me ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to extend `FlatFileItemWriter` to write data to a csv file. That built-in reader can be used for that. Here is a quick example:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<Person> itemWriter() {
    return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Person>()
            .resource(new FileSystemResource("persons.csv"))
            .name("personItemWriter")
            .delimited()
            .names("id", "name")
            .build();
}
```

Comment: I recognize that but Im restricted by the project architecture, which requires creating a seperate class for every component including the writer. is there a way you can show me how to transform your example into a class form ?

Comment: `Im restricted by the project architecture, which requires creating a seperate class for every component including the writer.`: Interesting! Just curious, why is that? If you REALLY can't use a class from Spring Batch as is, then you can just create a class `class MyCustomWriter extends FlatFileItemWriter` and use that instead (you won't have a builder through, so you can create an instance of `MyCustomWriter` and use setters to configure properties).